# How to combine both javascripts scripts below to include ajax call for a server time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am struggling how to combine and make ajax call to check the server time upon loading the javascript so the time will be server time and not client time ?

**Ajax function to call script with time():**

```
  $.fn.jclock.getServerOffset = function(el) {
    //Want to make a synchronous call to the server to get the server time.
    $.ajax({
        url: "Time.php",
        async: false,
        context: el,
        success: function(result) {
            var serverDate = new Date(+(result) * 1000); //Convert the seconds to a number, and multiple by 1000 to get milliseconds.
            var clientDate = new Date();

            $this = $(this.context[0]);

            $this.serverOffset = clientDate - serverDate; //Set the offset between server and client.
}
});
};
```

And my countdown timer function ... so I must edit the first `new Date()` but I really have no idea. Please give me a clue how I may do it?

**Javascript for the countdown timer:**

```
<script>
var currday = new Date();
var day = currdate.getDay();
var hrs = currdate.getHours();
var hrs0 = currdate.getHours();
var hrs00 = currdate.getHours();
var mins = currdate.getMinutes();
var secs = currdate.getSeconds();
var CSWday = 7;
var CSWhrs = 19;
var FThrs1 = 6;
var FThrs2 = 14;
var FThrs3 = 22;
var BDWhrs1 = 5;
var BDWhrs2 = 11;
var BDWhrs3 = 17;
var BDWhrs4 = 23;
var FTmins1 = 59;
var FTsecs1 = 60;
var hrsOut = 0;
var hrsOut2 = 0;

var hrs1 = FThrs1 - hrs;
var hrs2 = FThrs2 - hrs;
var hrs3 = FThrs3 - hrs;

var hrs01 = BDWhrs1 - hrs0;
var hrs02 = BDWhrs2 - hrs0;
var hrs03 = BDWhrs3 - hrs0;
var hrs04 = BDWhrs4 - hrs0;

var day = CSWday - day;
var hrs001 = CSWhrs - hrs00;

if (day == 7)
    day = 0;

if ((hrs > 22) || ((hrs >= 0) && (hrs < 7)))
{
    if (hrs > 22)
        hrsOut = 7;
    else
        hrsOut = hrs1;
}
if ((hrs > 6) && (hrs < 15))
    hrsOut = hrs2;
if ((hrs > 14) && (hrs < 23))
    hrsOut = hrs3;

if ((hrs0 > 23) || ((hrs0 >= 0) && (hrs0 < 6)))
{
    if (hrs0 > 23)
        hrsOut2 = 6;
    else
        hrsOut2 = hrs01;
}
if ((hrs0 > 5) && (hrs0 < 12))
    hrsOut2 = hrs02;
if ((hrs0 > 11) && (hrs0 < 18))
    hrsOut2 = hrs03;
if ((hrs0 > 17) && (hrs0 <= 23))
    hrsOut2 = hrs04;

mins = FTmins1 - mins;
secs = FTsecs1 - secs;

var counter=setInterval(FTTimer, 1000);
var counter=setInterval(BDWTimer, 1000);
var counter=setInterval(CSWTimer, 1000);
```

Comment: do you really need to request every 1 second just to check for the time?

Comment: No, I just want it to be server time. Could be only once when the page is loaded. I don't want to use the users/browser time because my countdown timer will be entirely incorrect if I do that, so how I can use my server time on that script ? Thanks for trying to help me, roullie.

Comment: you can just echo . like `<?php echo date('H:i:s'); ?>`

Comment: No, I can't use it on my full script. There is no php on that. So, I really need to include the Time.php to synchronize it with the server upon loading the page. Possible to combine these both above somehow?

Comment: Get the time offset from the server ONCE when the page loads and then use the local clock to count time from there using that offset.   Much better than constantly getting time from server.

Comment: How to do that actually? That's what I am trying ...

Comment: I am really struggling and if someone can show me an example will be really awesome. Thanks if someone is willing to help me out ..